# Query to return multiple group by sets in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

We have a table with hundreds of millions of rows, and we want to query some group by counts on some subset of it. Currently we run multiple queries, one for each group, but it seems like that would probably cause multiple scans of the data. For instance, lets say you have a table People with the columns:
FirstName
LastName
Age
State
Country
ZipCode

And you want to run the following queries:

```
SELECT State, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM People
WHERE -- complicated where clause --
GROUP BY State;

SELECT Country, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM People
WHERE -- complicated where clause --
GROUP BY Country;

SELECT Country, AVG(Age) AS avg_age
FROM People
WHERE -- complicated where clause --
GROUP BY Country;
```

The issue is that this will result in having to scan the data multiple times. Is there a way to scan the data once, calculate multiple summary tables? Each one of these queries takes around a second or two, and it seems like it would be more efficient if the data could be run through once, and multiple result sets be returned.

Is that even possible with MYSQL?

Comment: This looks tricky, maybe impossible, to me.

Comment: If the complicated where clause is the same for all, you can put that data in a temporary table. Then you can perform the grouped queries on the temporary table. This will be more efficient than doing the full queries.